# C# Invoking method by timer.Elapsed and by click

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, system.timers.timer

I have some problem with Timer.

This is my code:

```
_uploadHelper = new DataProcessorUploadHelper((sender, args) => Start())

public void Start()
{
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (UploadHelper.UploadState == UploadState.UploadOn)
            {
                UploadHelper.IncrementSavingRequestCounter();
            }
            else
            {
                UploadHelper.StopTimer();
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    UploadHelper.UploadState = UploadState.UploadOn;

                    UploadData();

                    UploadHelper.UploadState = UploadState.UploadOff;
                }
                UploadHelper.StartTimer();
            }
        });
}
```

UploadState is implemented in this way

```
    private int _uploadState;

    public UploadState UploadState
    {
        get { return (UploadState)_uploadState; }
        set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref _uploadState, (int)value); }
    }
```

I'm using  System.Timers.Timer which should call Start method with 10 minutes interval (is implemented inside my helper class) .

```
    private Timer _intervalTimer;
    private long _savingRequestsCounter;

    public DataProcessorUploadHelper(ElapsedEventHandler callback)
    {
        UploadState = UploadState.UploadOff;;
        _intervalTimer = new Timer();
        _intervalTimer.Interval = UploadIntervalTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
        _intervalTimer.Elapsed += callback;
        _intervalTimer.Start();
        _intervalTimer.Enabled = true;
    } 
    public void StartTimer()
    {
        _intervalTimer.Start();
    }
    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        _intervalTimer.Start();
        _intervalTimer.Stop();
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        _intervalTimer.Stop();
    }
    public void IncrementSavingRequestCounter()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _savingRequestsCounter);
    }

    public void DecrementSavingRequestCounter()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _savingRequestsCounter);
    }
```

Also this method is called too when user clicks specific button.

And my trouble.

Timer invokes Start method => UploadHelper.UploadState = UploadState.UploadOn.

Moreover should be locked by _lock.

But when user clicks during UploadData()
I see that UploadState = UploadState.UploadOff
and is not locked.

What's wrong with this piece of code?

Why State is different when timer call this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > "...Moreover should be locked by _lock"

yes if **_lock** is declared as **static** in your case.

As Elapsed-Event of your Timer causes a call of your UploadData() in a separate Thread, the _lock (if not static) is every time not the same _lock and does not serve as a synchronizing object.

2. If your timer is from  [System.Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then there exists also another way to synchronize:
   see [SynchronizingObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)